# Help using Load Pull in ADS

Tags: load, ads

I'd like to ask for some help with performing a Load Pull simulation in ADS. I tried using the DesignGuide utility but am not sure how to connect the Load Pull Instr shown in the attachment and which voltages and loads to select initially. Anyone?

The circuit shown is my own and on which I'd like to perform Load Pull.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To perform load-pull, you need some terminator, and a variable-phase-shift element. How to generate variable-delay or variable-phaseshiftt?

Comment: I was hoping someone here could instruct me how to connect the Load Pull Instr to the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the source of load pull instrument to gate terminal and load to drain terminal and run the simulation. Also set drain and gate voltages in the load pull instrument.